# Trying to understand how these if else statements close correctly

Tags: ruby

```
# A name is valid is if satisfies all of the following:
# - contains at least a first name and last name, separated by spaces
# - each part of the name should be capitalized


def is_valid_name(str) 
word_Split = str.split(" ")
if word_Split.length >= 2 
word_Split.each do |x| 
  if x == x.capitalize
  else 
      return false
  end
end
return true
end
return false
end

puts is_valid_name("Kush Patel") # => true
puts is_valid_name("Daniel") # => false
puts is_valid_name("Robert Downey Jr") # => true
puts is_valid_name("ROBERT DOWNEY JR") # => false
```

In this code above, I understand the placement of the the first if/else statement. What I am having issues understanding is, do the 2 ends under the first return false, close the .each loop and the method?

What does the return true and return false outside the loop even do? I'm trying understand to read this code.

Since I am still new to coding, I have been writing if/else statements as: if this, do that. else, do this. or use an elsif in between.

I appreciate any help in understanding how this reads. I took a look at c++ if/else statements and they were a little easier to read. Using { } to separate them. Thanks for your patience and understanding.

Comment: Try indenting the code consistently and it should be more obvious which `end` corresponds with what.

Comment: It's recommended that variables and method names be written in [snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). For example, `word_split` rather than `word_Split` or `wordSplit`. You don't have to do that but 99%+ of Rubyists do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I would do is take the code and fix the indentation and add newlines where helpful to increase readability. Next I've added inline comments to explain a bit of what is going on.

```
def is_valid_name(str) 
  word_Split = str.split(" ")

  # at least two words?
  if word_Split.length >= 2 
    word_Split.each do |x| 
      # This if block is empty and control falls through to [1]
      # once all the words in the loop pass the check. This if/else
      # could be replaced by `unless`
      if x == x.capitalize
        
      else
        # Immediately exit the function and return false since
        # a single word in the loop was not capitalized
        return false
      end
    end

    # [1] This handles the case where 
    # each word had a proper first letter capitalized
    return true
  end
  
  # There was zero or one word, return false. 
  # Technically in ruby, the word `return` is optional
  # for the last line in the method
  return false 
end
```

> In this code above, I understand the placement of the the first if/else statement. What I am having issues understanding is, do the 2 ends under the first return false, close the .each loop and the method?

No. The two `end` immediately after the first `return false` closes the `if/else` statement, then the loop. The two follow `ends` close the first `if` statement and then the method.

> What does the return true and return false outside the loop even do? I'm trying understand to read this code.

The `return true` handles the case all the words (at least 2 or more) all started with a capital letter. The `return false` handles the case where there is only zero or one word after attempting the split.

As a former C/C++ dev, I recommend you look at Ruby conditionals as a good point to continue reading. Specifically learn about `if, else, elsif, and unless` as well as trailing conditionals.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for taking the time to do this. I've been struggling on learning to write code. Moving  from a creative field, to something like this. Thank you. I'll brush up more on if, else, elsif and unless and trailing conditionals.

Comment: @MildManneredMan nice to hear, keep it up! It's a very rewarding journey of growth to switch fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think Matthew already gave great answers to your questions.

Learning a new language isn't easy especially because you do not only have to understand the different syntax and the different concepts but also need to get familiar with common idioms and common coding styles.

The Ruby community, for example, uses underscore variable names, prefers methods names to end with a question mark when the method returns an boolean, and because of implicit returns is avoids using explicit return values in many case.

That said, I agree that the code example in your question is hard to understand. Mostly for the reason that it doesn't follow common Ruby idioms and best practices.

Just as an example I would like to show a refactored version that behaves exactly the same and that IMHO looks more Rubyish:

```
def valid_name?(name) 
  parts = name.split

  parts.size >= 2 && 
    parts.all? { |part| part == part.capitalize }
end

valid_name?("Kush Patel") # => true
valid_name?("Daniel") # => false
valid_name?("Robert Downey Jr") # => true
valid_name?("ROBERT DOWNEY JR") # => false
```

Comment: This was a lot easier to read. Thank you.  I tend to feel a little stupid learning something new like this. But, it's not detered me from trying. Thank you for taking the time to answer as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for that.

```
def valid_name?(name)
  name.match? /\A(?:\p{Upper}\p{Lower}+)(?: +\p{Upper}\p{Lower}+)+\z/
end
```

```
valid_name?("Kush Patel")        #=> true
valid_name?("Cher")              #=> false
valid_name?("Robert Downey Jr")  #=> true
valid_name?("ROBERT DOWNEY JR")  #=> false
```

See [String#match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F).

The regular expression can be made self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing* mode.

```
/\A            # match beginning of string
 (?:           # begin a non-capture group
   \p{Upper}   # match an upper-case Unicode letter
   \p{Lower}+  # match one or more lower-case Unicode letters
 )             # end non-capture group
 (?:           # begin a non-capture group
   \ +         # match one or more spaces
   \p{Upper}   # match an upper-case Unicode letter
   \p{Lower}+  # match one or more lower-case Unicode letters
 )+            # end non-capture group and execute it one or more times
 \z            # match end of string
 /x            # employ free-spacing regex definition mode
```

`\p{Upper}` (`\p{Lower}`) can alternatively be written `\p{Lu}` (`\p{Ll}`) or `[[:upper:]]` (`[[:lower:]]`). If ASCII is satisfactory one could use `[A-Z]` (`[a-z]`). See [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html).

Note that I used `..(?: +\p{Upper}\p{Lower}+)..` within the method definition and `..(?:\ +\p{Upper}\p{Lower}+)..` when expressing the regular expression in free-spacing mode (the space character is escaped in the latter). That's because free-spacing mode removes all spaces before the expression is parsed. To preserve spaces they must be escaped, placed within a character class (`[ ]`) or replaced with `\p{Zs}`. I would advise against writing `\s`, `[[:space:]]` and `\p{Space}` as they also match newlines (`\n`) which can be problematic in some cases.